# what does the phrase "To bid on the drumsticks" mean?

Tags: meaning

I couldn't find the translation of this phrase so I'm looking for the meaning of it.

Comment: There's no context whatsoever in this question. A link would be nice too.

Comment: What @T.E.D. said. Without any further context, the title could refer to [this](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.Xdrumsticks&_nkw=drumsticks&_sacat=0&_from=R40).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are asking about the phrase as it's used in the [following quote](http://hungergamesdwtc.net/quotes/catching-fire/) from *Catching Fire* :

> …in the Hob, the standard protocol for someone showing up with a wild turkey is for everybody to bid on the drumsticks. – Katniss Everdeen, p. 108

(In other contexts, such as “[Signed Neil Peart drumsticks up for bid in Music Empowers Foundation fundraiser auction](http://www.rushisaband.com/blog/2012/03/06/3018/Signed-Neil-Peart-drumsticks-up-for-bid-in-Music-Empowers-Foundation-fundraiser-auction?p=1&n=10&o=ASC)”, the meaning is more obvious: bidding on a pair of wooden drumsticks formerly used by a drummer in a band.)

In the turkey context, *[drumsticks](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drumstick#English)* are  “The second joint of the leg bone of a chicken or other fowl, as meat”, which some people prefer.  It may be that the quote refers just to that part of the turkey, or  “the drumsticks” might be [metonymy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metonymy) for the whole turkey.  Either way, there's a hint the wild turkey will be cut up and cooked, not kept for a pet.

Comment: You are right. This is the quote from Catching Fire. Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It means that in wars they would send kids and midgets in the first of the army without any weapons so they were not a lot of chances for this fellas to survive really it a sad story I hope humanity won't do more shit like that again.

So to "bid on the drumstick" - to bid on something with very low chances or to bid on leftovers that's my logic maybe there is a more informed answer.

There is also a direct referral for that in "The tin can" by Gaunter Grass were the main character is a drummer put on another time and space

Comment: Do you, ah, have a source for that?

Comment: http://articles.washingtonpost.com/2012-02-21/lifestyle/35444659_1_drummer-boys-younger-boys-young-boys

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drummer_boy_(military)

Comment: Oh, I already know about drummer boys and their horrible history. I want to know if you have a source for their being connected to the phrase "bid on the drumsticks."

Comment: The source I have is my logic as stated "that's my logic", however i think it makes a perfect sense if it true so it highly possible it is true. I have some other opinion about trying to find a quote for every claim rather using logic and other scientific an thought methods. How this theory of the drum bid sound to you? I think that the term "drumstick" does have its historical weight shown here and even if the author who use it in modern time wasn't directly aware of that meaning at the moment when she wrote it, it is still there.

Comment: I'd say that's more speculation than logic, then. There may be some validity to it, but the connection seems tenuous without a credible source, especially given the OP's confirmation that the line is from *Catching Fire* and is not a common idiom. Thanks for clarifying the basis of your answer!